# Facebook JS SDK returns no results

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I ran an example copied from:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

(I only changed my APP_ID)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MY_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.api('/platform/posts', { limit: 3 }, function(response) {
  for (var i=0, l=response.length; i<l; i++) {
    var post = response[i];
    if (post.message) {
      alert('Message: ' + post.message);
    } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
      alert('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
    }
  }
});
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Nothing shows in the browser. There is no JavaScript errors in console (Opera 11). Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not logged in. You need to authenticate the user to get an oauth token in place first before you can run this part of the code:

```
     FB.api('/platform/posts', { limit: 3 }, function(response) {
      for (var i=0, l=response.length; i<l; i++) {
        var post = response[i];
        if (post.message) {
          alert('Message: ' + post.message);
        } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name) {
          alert('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
        }
      }
    });
```

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and realized that the example is not parsing the response correctly. The object has a property **data** which is actually the Array to be parsed.

Another point is that you need a token to do this operation. So your code should be:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    var fbToken; // Highly recommended to make it global
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'MY_ID', // App ID
            channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                fbToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;  // Save it for another requests
                FB.api('/platform/posts', {limit:3}, function(response){
                    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++)
                    {
                        var post = response.data[i];
                        if (post.message)
                        {
                          alert('Message: ' + post.message);
                        } else if (post.attachment && post.attachment.name)
                        {
                          alert('Attachment: ' + post.attachment.name);
                        }
                      }
                });
            } else {
                // User did not accept oAuth
            }
        });
    }
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```